# redirect to another URL using submit button in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have submit button and i want to redirect in another URL (hard coded) this URL

> https://www.ccavenue.com/shopzone/cc_details.jsp

my code :

```
<%= form_tag @ccavanue do |f| , url => "https://www.ccavenue.com/shopzone/cc_details.jsp",       :html => :method => "put" %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :my_field, @MerchantId, :id => 'merchant_id' %>
<%= submit_tag "Click Me"  %>
<% end %>
```

i want to redirect another website URL with this submit button . please guided me.

Comment: what you write seems like you want to `post` to a url in another site. That is not a good idea, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423682/cross-domain-form-posting . If you want to redirect after that post, you should add the relevant code to your controller to perform a get request to that location.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to following:

```
<%= form_for @ccavanue, url: "https://www.ccavenue.com/shopzone/cc_details.jsp" do |f| %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :my_field, @MerchantId, :id => 'merchant_id' %>
   <%= f.submit "Click Me"  %>
<% end %>
```

**In Rails** a form is designed to **create** or **update** a resource and reflects the identity of the resource in several ways:

1. The url that the form is sent to (the form element's action attribute) should result in a request being routed to the appropriate controller action (with the appropriate :id parameter in the case of an existing resource),
2. Input fields should be named in such a way that in the controller their values appear in the appropriate places within the params hash, and
3. For an existing record, when the form is initially displayed, input fields corresponding to attributes of the resource should show the current values of those attributes.

In Rails this is achieved by creating form using **form_for** where:

If we want to create any object we use **POST** method within url and **PUT** method if we are trying to update an existing record.

Rails framework is smart enough to use **POST or PUT** method by itself looking at the url of the form. So in this case we need not use **method** parameter within form_for url.

Probably you can start with [Michael Hartl's tutorial](http://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning)

Comment: I am not sure why you are using "put" method to form_for but try not to pass method parameter in form_for

Comment: I am not aware about this. i am in new in ruby and i want to purchase book of Ruby on Rails for best beginning to learn . please guided me

Comment: I have modified the answer with relevant guide to Ruby on Rails. Please look at the edited answer