# Form post method is not working on server

Tags: javascript, html, post

I have created some Register Forms in my localhost. That Register form is working on my localhost and in another testing server.But when I deployed it in another server, then the post method is not working. I have used JavaScript for posting the form and I also tried with normal method using html on that server. Both method are not working on that server. In browser "**Developer tools**", in the "**Console Window**", the below error is displayed:

> error: POST http://mycarer.com.au/db/complite_regi_db.php 403
>   (Forbidden)

Following is my JavaScript for the Registration form.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('#basic_info_register').submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
var val_form= $('#basic_info_register').serialize();
$.post('db/complite_regi_db.php',val_form,function(data){
               window.location.replace("finder_image_upload.php");
                });
      });
});
```

Please can some one give me any solution.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423682/cross-domain-form-posting

Comment: you are trying it to post to another server, may be jsonp can help you

Comment: When i post it using simple HTML post method, i will get following error message.Forbidden

"You don't have permission to access /db/complite_regi_db.php on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request"

Answer (score 0):

Does this page, `http://mycarer.com.au/db/complite_regi_db.php` allow `POST` request. From the `403 Forbidden error message`, it looks like `POST` requests are not allowed.

Comment: When i post it using simple HTML post method, i will get following error message.Forbidden

"You don't have permission to access /db/complite_regi_db.php on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request"

Comment: then how can allow post method on this server??

Comment: In the Web server, where http://mycarer.com.au/db/complite_regi_db.php is hosted, the POST method should be enabled.