# Entering data in a input from an other host

Tags: javascript, php, python

I have a question, is possible to send data from an other host in an input of another host?

For example, my host is www.example.com and i wanna send data to an input from the host called www.example2.com. Is it possible with PHP, Python, JavaScript?

Comment: Yes it is .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's possible simply just add action to the domain this in your form

```
<form action="http://someotherdomain.com">
```

or via ajax sample code with button submit

```
<script>
   $(document).on("click", "#yourbtnSubmitId", function(e) {
      $.ajax({

          type: 'POST',     
          data: $("form").serialize(),
          url: 'http://someotherdomain/anotherpage',  
            success: function(res) {
               alert("done");
            }   

        });

<script>
```

here more helpful reference

- [here for html post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423682/cross-domain-form-posting)
- [here via ajax php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain)

hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

it is very possible to send the data to a different host, however you have to call to that server in your connect db statement;
for example your other host is mysql.server2.com , you may include the following in your current host db connect file.

```
$link = mysql_connect("mysql.server2.com", "username", "password")
      or die("Could not connect");
        $db = mysql_select_db("your_db", $link)
    or die("Could not select database");
```

however, from practice, I would not recommend this method since one server may be experiencing downtime which will affect the other.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can send data to another host from your site. You can do this by following ways-

1. For PHP - It is done cURL. Refer this [link](https://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/php-curl)
2. For Javascript - Simply by ajax call. Refer this [link](http://www.javatpoint.com/ajax-tutorial)