# HTML form on an HTTPS site that submits its content to a completely different HTTPS site

Tags: html, http, https

Is it possible/allowed to create an HTML form on an HTTPS site that submits its content to a completely different (even domain is different) HTTPS site or are there issues, i.e. the browser shows an alert?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross Domain Form POSTing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423682/cross-domain-form-posting)

Answer (score -1):

It is a Mixed Content
if you have a `non SSL form action` The page at secured page was loaded over a secure connection, but contains a form which targets an insecure endpoint. This endpoint should be made available over a secure connection.
It makes a warning on a secured page

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explained me too well. Both sites are HTTPS sites but they are different sites, with different domains. I do know that an HTTPS form submitting to an HTTP action gives a browser warning.

Comment: @CristianVeronesi , So otherwise, You wont have any problem