# POST Values to another application

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I am struggling for the past two days, also not even know whether its possible to do or not.
Actually, my requirement is simple, i need to pass the logged-in user details from one application to another application (external). 
Problem is i don't have a source code of external application. Is it possible to fill the user details automatically and click the login button of external application. Can any one please suggest me whether its possible or not.

I have tried by the following approach which i have found in stack-overflow

```
 var htmlForm = "<form id='myform' method='POST' action='//www.xxx.com/?/yyyy/Index.cshtml'>" +
            //    "<input type='hidden' id='usr_name' value='xxxx' />" +
            //"</form>";

            ////Submit the form
        //$(htmlForm).appendTo("body").submit();
```

Comment: Yes, you can do this either from the client or from the server side. I think the most promising way is an ajax post request. You can easily do that with jquery (which you're using obviously).

Comment: If the other website uses standard form transmission (as opposed to AJAX) and doesn't reject the request based on the wrong referrer, this should be possible. We would have to take a look at the other website though. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423682/cross-domain-form-posting

Comment: what is the problem with current code? is there any console errors or network errors?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But how can i get the values and submit the form in external application.

Comment: not getting error its redirecting only. but i need to fill the user details  and click the login button automatically