# It is bad practice to POST a form to a different web server?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ghost-blog

I use a CMS that doesn't make it easy to add a NodeJS route to handle data sent by my forms.

Would the following scenario be bad practice, is it unsafe ?

Server 1 (Ghost CMS) : **www**.domain.com

```
<form action="form.domain.com/sign-up" method="post">
...
</form>
```

Server 2 (Express.js) : **form**.domain.com

```
app.post('/sign-up', (req, res) => {
    //do something
});
```

Comment: It is a cross-origin POST, but since it's not going through JavaScript, it's not subject to same-origin rules. See [Cross Domain Form POSTing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11423682/215552)

Answer (score 0):

No it is not. You have just created your own API via Express.js
So, it is normal.