# why my formdata POST isn't blocked by Cors policy?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, axios, multer

I got confused regarding one query: when I call POST request from frontend running at a different origin to my backend running at a different origin, why is my POST request containing form data isn't blocked by CORS policy??

My Nodejs code contains the following lines of code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer({
    dest:"uploads/"
})
app.use("/image",express.static(path.join(__dirname,"uploads")))
app.post("/upload",upload.single('profile'),(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.file);
    res.send("uploaded");
})

app.listen(8080,(err)=>{
    if (err) {
        console.log("Opps");
    }
},()=>{
    console.log("listening at port 8080");
})
```

My Frontend code:
Suppose I am running my index.html from `http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <title>Form with Photos</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <form onsubmit="handleForm(event)">
        <input type="text" name="username"> <br>
        <input type="file" name="profile"> <br>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
   
    <script>
        const handleForm =(e)=>{
          let username = document.querySelector("input[name='username']");
          let profile = document.querySelector("input[name='profile']");
          let fd = new FormData();
          fd.append("username",username.value);
          fd.append("profile",profile.files[0]);
          axios({
              method:"post",
              url:"http://localhost:8080/upload",
              data:fd
          }).then((response)=>{
              console.log(response.body);
          }).catch((e)=>{
              console.log(e);
          })
     
          e.preventDefault();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**When I click the `submit button, my files and input are successfully submitted to my backend. But I am wondering my server` http://localhost:8080 `and client:`http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html `is different origins. But why CORS didn't block this post request? Note:`I am just eager to know whether form-data post request through API isn't blocked by CORS or not?`**

Comment: You don't need to be part of the same domain to submit a POST request; you can POST data to anywhere.

Answer (score 7):

For web compatibility reasons CORS doesn't apply to cross-origin form posts. It only applies to what I would call "dynamic" requests (e.g. AJAX, fetch, and a few others).

This is because HTML forms pre-date the CORS specification.

When CORS was introduced they couldn't change this behaviour without potentially breaking existing website functionality.

Here is some more information:

- MDN page that lists the requests that are subject to CORS: [What requests use CORS?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#what_requests_use_cors)
- Previous stack questions:

  - https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/221770/cors-error-but-only-from-ajax-and-not-from-html-form
  - [Cross Domain Form POSTing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423682/cross-domain-form-posting)
- How to prevent security issues from cross-site request forgery (CSRF) requests:

  - [How to block cross-origin access](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#how_to_block_cross-origin_access)