# how to fill and submit forms to a different domain

Tags: javascript, forms, curl, post

i'm trying to submit a form automatically to a completely different website that's owned by a third party, the goal is trying to help my company users to get information without making them do anything other then clicking a link.

i have tried a few ways that i searched from google

1. cross domain posting [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423682/cross-domain-form-posting) 
   in my case i tried making the form a similar with the destination form and had no luck
2. using curl [source](https://journalxtra.com/linux/howto-pass-data-variables-to-curl-to-autofill-web-forms/) 
   i tried this and it does not fill any form for me, i saved the curl response to an html file and open it in Firefox ( i don't know anyway else to test it )
3. i tried using URL params 
   i don't know why it does not work but my theory is its filtered for security reasons

the current stack of the app that i'm currently working on is using nextjs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've finally solved it.

Number 1 is the solution, but make sure the destination for the POST has the same names for the fields. I don't know why, but some of the destination websites has different names in the browser and in actual forms that are processed.